# Move semantics in derived-to-base class conversions

Tags: c++, c++17, move-semantics, derived-class, object-slicing

Consider the following class `Buffer`, which contains an `std::vector` object:

```
#include <vector>
#include <cstddef>

class Buffer {
   std::vector<std::byte> buf_;
protected:
   Buffer(std::byte val): buf_(1024, val) {}
};
```

Now, consider the function `make_zeroed_buffer()` below. The class `BufferBuilder` is a *[local class](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/local-class-in-c/)* that publicly derives from `Buffer`. Its purpose is to create `Buffer` objects.

```
Buffer make_zeroed_buffer() {
   struct BufferBuilder: Buffer {
      BufferBuilder(): Buffer(std::byte{0}) {}
   };

   BufferBuilder buffer;

   // ...

   return buffer;
}
```

If no copy elision takes place, is the `buffer` object above guaranteed to be moved from?

My reasoning is the following:

1. The expression `buffer` in the `return` statement is an *lvalue*. Since it is a *local object* that is not going to be used anymore, the compiler casts it into an *rvalue*.
2. The `buffer` object is of type `BufferBuilder`. `Buffer` is a public base class of `BufferBuilder`, so this `BufferBuilder` object is implicitly converted into a `Buffer` object.
3. This conversion, in turn, implies an implicit reference-to-derived to a reference-to-base conversion (i.e., a reference to `BufferBuilder` to a reference to `Buffer`). That reference to `BufferBuilder` is an rvalue reference (see 1.), which turns into an rvalue reference to `Buffer`.
4. The rvalue reference to `Buffer` matches `Buffer`'s move constructor, which is used to construct the `Buffer` object that `make_zeroed_buffer()` returns by value. As a result, the return value is constructed by moving from the `Buffer` part of the object `buffer`.

Comment: *If no copy elision takes place* What makes you think that this condition will ever be satisfied? From my recollection, when you explicitly `return std::move(buffer);` the compiler (clang) will issue a warning about surpressing copy elision.

Comment: @Walter What makes you think then that copy elision will always be satisfied?

Comment: If I remember well, in this very particular case you have to use `return std::move(buffer)`

Comment: @BiagioFesta can you please elaborate?

Comment: No copy elision. The next statement is violated: In a return statement, when the operand is a prvalue of the same class type (ignoring cv-qualification) as the function return type

Comment: *The buffer object is of type BufferBuilder. Buffer is a public base class of BufferBuilder, so this BufferBuilder object is implicitly converted into a Buffer object.* It is not true. The BufferBuilder object is copied implicitly to a Builder object. You confused with pointers to a derived class.

Comment: @S.M. Doesn't it apply to references as well?

Comment: Yes, it does. Your code does not have any reference. Except the implicit Buffer's copy constructor.

Comment: According to the common programming patterns the BufferBuilder must not derive the being built class.

Comment: Also, in your 'step 3', as of C++20, that **never** happens. There is no situation in which the compiler will notice that a variable is no longer used and implicitly convert an lvalue into an rvalue. One must always explicitly state this desire by using `::std::move`. It could be added as a 'feature'. But that's one of those features that I don't think has much benefit, especially as compared to the added complexity it would introduce.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**RVO Optimisation**

> If no copy elision takes place [...]

Actually, *copy elision* will not take place (without *if*).

From C++ standard [class.copy.elision#1](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.copy.elision#1):

> is permitted in the following circumstances [...]:
>
> -- in a return statement in a function with a class return type, when the expression is the name of a non-volatile automatic object ([...]) **with the same type** (ignoring cv-qualification) as the function return type [...]

Technically, when you return a *derived* class and a slicing operation takes place, the RVO cannot be applied.

Technically RVO works constructing the local object on the returning space on the stack frame.

```
|--------------|
| local vars   |
|--------------|
| return addr  |
|--------------|
| return obj   |
|--------------|
```

Generally, a derived class can have a different memory layout than its parent (different size, alignments, ...). So there is no guarantee the local object (*derived*) can be constructed in the place reserved for the returned object (*parent*).

---

**Implicit move**

Now, what about *implicit move*?

> is the buffer object above guaranteed to be moved from???

In short: no. On the contrary, it is guaranteed the object will be copied!

In this particular case *implicit move* will not be performed because of *slicing*.

In short, this happens because the overload resolution fails.
It tries to match against the move-constructor (`Buffer::Buffer(Buffer&&)`) whereas you have a `BufferBuild` object). So it fallbacks on the copy constructor.

From C++ standard [class.copy.elision#3](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.copy.elision#3):

> [...] if the type of the first parameter of the selected constructor or the return_­value overload is not an rvalue reference to the object's type (possibly cv-qualified), overload resolution is performed again, considering the object as an lvalue.

Therefore, since the first overload resolution fails (as I have said above), the expression will be treated as an *lvalue* (and not an *rvalue*), inhibiting the *move*.

An interesting talk by Arthur O'Dwyer specifically refers to this case. [Youtube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hA1WNtNyNbo&t=730s).

---

**Additional Note**

On clang, you can pass the flag `-Wmove` in order to detect this kind of problems.
Indeed [for your code](https://godbolt.org/z/QtpnvJ):

```
local variable 'buffer' will be copied despite being returned by name [-Wreturn-std-move]

   return buffer;

          ^~~~~~

<source>:20:11: note: call 'std::move' explicitly to avoid copying

   return buffer;
```

clang directly suggests you to use `std::move` on the return expression.

Comment: In standardese, the implicit move is disallowed because "the type of the first parameter of the selected constructor (`Buffer&&`) is not an rvalue reference to the object's type (`BufferBuilder&&`)" http://eel.is/c++draft/class.copy.elision#3.sentence-2

Comment: Yeah, that what I've written (with other words). But thank you, maybe I can rephrase better and add a reference to the standard.

Comment: You phrased it fine, I just wanted to show the "proof".

Comment: If my reading of the spec is correct, this modification of the local class should make the compiler move it: `struct BufferBuilder {  BufferBuilder():buffer(std::byte{0}) {} Buffer buffer; operator Buffer() && { return (Buffer&&)buffer; } };` Because there is no "selected constructor" anymore. (EDIT: needs a public constructor in Buffer :/)

Comment: Clang disagrees with my reading. GCC agrees. Clang says: "<source>:16:7: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'BufferBuilder' to 'BufferBuilder' for object argument

      operator Buffer() && { return (Buffer&&)buffer; }". I think that this is a bug in Clang.

Comment: Does GCC have a flag equivalent to `-Wmove`?

Comment: @Eric No, it doesn't as far as I know

Answer (score -1):

The object buffer from make_zeroed_buffer() will destroyed after will be made its copy with the help of Buffers' copy constructor for return value.